# Move items from one list to another and remove certain part of the string

Tags: python, list

I have this list with IDs and titles

```
myemails = [12345, 56789, 456789, 54321, 98765, 'Sample Title: Title number one', 'Sample Title: Title number two', 'Sample Title: Title number three', 'Sample Title: Title number four', 'Sample Title: Title number five']
```

I'm looking for a way to split this list into two separate lists where in one only Ids will be stored and in the other one titles without 'Sample Title:' part of the string:

```
myemailId = [12345, 56789, 456789, 54321, 98765]
myemailTitle = ['Title number one', 'Title number two', 'Title number three', 'Title number four', 'Title number five']
```

my code so far:

```
from collections import defaultdict
myemails = [12345, 56789, 456789, 54321, 98765, 'Sample Title: Title number one', 'Sample Title: Title number two', 'Sample Title: Title number three', 'Sample Title: Title number four', 'Sample Title: Title number five'] 

d = defaultdict(myemails)
for x in myList:
   d[type(x)].append(x)

emailId = print d[int]
emailTitle = print  d[str]
```

However it throws this error:

```
TypeError: first argument must be callable or None
```

Can someone help me with this please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you meant `d = defaultdict(list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
myemailid = [item for item in myemails if str(item).isdigit()]
myemailtitle = [item.replace("Sample Title: ", "") for item in myemails if not str(item).isdigit()]

print(myemailid)
print(myemailtitle)
```

This prints:

```
[12345, 56789, 456789, 54321, 98765]
['Title number one', 'Title number two', 'Title number three', 'Title number four', 'Title number five']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your code

- `defaultdict` should be initialized with type but you init it with `myemails` instead of `list`
- you assign the result of `print` to a variable (`print` returns `None`)

Try instead this one:

```
myemails = [12345, 56789, 456789, 54321, 98765, 'Sample Title: Title number one', 'Sample Title: Title number two', 'Sample Title: Title number three', 'Sample Title: Title number four', 'Sample Title: Title number five'] 

ids = []
titles = []
for x in myemails:
    if type(x) == int:
        ids.append(x)  
    elif type(x) == str:
        titles.append(x)
    else:
        print("unsupported type {} of {}".format(type(x),x))

print(ids)
print(titles)
```